# Mysql database encoding not working with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, mysql-8.0

I am using mysql 8, and spring-jdbc 4.3.18.RELEASE, i configured my datasource in the applicationContext.xml file under WEB-INF directory like this:

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=utf8" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
```

my configuration class is like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("package...")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringJdbcConfig {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=utf8");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mysqlDataSource")
    public static JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    sqlScriptEncoding: UTF-8
```

my table charset is set: charset = utf8mb4;

but when in my input form i try to write characters like àòèùì it writes in the correspondig column the values: Ã²ÃÂ¹ ....etc.

how do i solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Also check the charset at column level (table charset and collation are used as default values for column definitions but it may have been changed at column level). Also I'm not sure about `useUnicode=yes`, it may be `useUnicode=true`.

Comment: i changed to useUnicode=true then altered the table but not working again

Comment: while debugging, i see that before my jdbcTemplate.query(... the variable used to fill the query is already set with strange characters. I wonder if the problem resides in my jsp, but i put this in the jsp: <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %> and after: <meta charset="UTF-8">